# SQL join a table with exact time or before it

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get a results table based on table2 with potential values not found in the table1.  For example lets say I have table1 with

```
time | col1 | col2
 10  |  a   |  b
 15  |  c   |  d
 23  |  e   |  f
 45  |  g   |  h
 61  |  i   |  j
 70  |  k   |  l
```

and table2 with

```
 time 
 8    
 23   
 55  
 72
```

results should be

```
time | col1 | col2
 8   | null |  null
 23  |  e   |  f
 55  |  g   |  h
 72  |  k   |  l
```

One way to look at the example is like a time table.  Say a time table of a president or a ruler.  So in year/time 10 `a b` became the ruler.  At year/time 8, there is no ruler so its null. At year/time 55, `g h` should still be the ruler.

Comment: Specify **precise** MySQL version. Does `time` column is defined as unique in `table1`?

Comment: Oh good question.  Time table is not unique in table1.  Assume MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left join` . . . along with `lead()` to get the end time:

```
select t2.*, t1.col1, t1.col2
from table2 t2 left join
     (select t1.*, lead(time) over (order by time) as next_time
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
     on t2.time >= t1.time and
        (t2.time < t1.next_time or t1.next_time is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using subqueries. Not the optimal way, but could work.

```
SELECT
 table2.time,
 (SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE time <= table2.time LIMIT 1 ORDER BY time desc) as col1,
 (SELECT col2 FROM table1 WHERE time <= table2.time LIMIT 1 ORDER BY time desc) as col2
FROM
 table2;
```